# How to adapt the app to multiple resolution in Windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, grid, viewbox

I have the layout code below in xaml

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel x:Name="TestStackPanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="TestScrollViewer" Height="300" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
         <GridView x:Name="TestGridView"
            Width="940"
            Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource TestItemPanelTemplate}" 
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TestItemStyle}" 
            SelectionMode="None"                                  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
       </ScrollViewer>
       <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="ClickMe" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,5,0,0" Click="TestButton_Click"/>
 </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This displays well in 1366*768 resolution, but if I change the resolution to 2560*1400, it couldn't displays as expected, I know it's certain, but how to adpat the layout to different resolutions? I have tried to add a ViewBox to encapsulate the Grid, it works well in FullScreenLandScape view, but when I change the app to Snap view, the Grid displays in a samll space.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Register to the `LayoutUpdated` event at the UI element. 
And re-calculate the layout according to `Window.Current.Bounds.Width`.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, could you please provide a link about it or some code?